# Appengine Backend stops processing tasks from push queue

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Since the past 1 month we have started facing this problem where the AppEngine backend randomly stops processing any job at all.
The closest other Qs I have seen is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJjen.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1jbm.png), but nothing of use.
My push queue configuration is

```
<queue>
  <name>MyFetcherQueue</name>
  <target>mybackend</target>
  <rate>30/m</rate>
  <max-concurrent-requests>1</max-concurrent-requests>
  <bucket-size>30</bucket-size>
  <retry-parameters>
    <task-retry-limit>10</task-retry-limit>
    <min-backoff-seconds>10</min-backoff-seconds>
    <max-backoff-seconds>200</max-backoff-seconds>
    <max-doublings>2</max-doublings>
  </retry-parameters>
</queue>
```

Standard Java App Engine with multiple modules, out of which one is a backend with Basic scaling, B4.

```
<runtime>java8</runtime>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<instance-class>B4</instance-class>
<basic-scaling>
  <max-instances>2</max-instances>
</basic-scaling>
```

Note, just to fix this problem, I have tried the following but to no avail:

1. Updated java from 7 to 8 - didnt work
2. Changed from earlier B1 to B4 - (thinking it could be a memory issue, but nothing as such in the logs)- didnt work
3. Changed queue processing rate to as low as 15/m with bucket size 15.
4. Changed max-instances from earlier 1 to 2 hoping that if atleast one instance hangs, the other should be able to process, but to no avail. I noticed (today) that when this issue occurred, the 2nd instance had only 2 requests (the other had 1400+), yet the new instance did not pick up the remaining tasks from the queue. The task ETA just kept increasing.
5. Updated Java Appengine sdk from earlier 1.9.57 to latest 1.9.63

Behavior: After a while (almost once per day now), the Backend would just stop responding and the tasks in this queue would be left as is. Only way to continue is to kill the backend instance from the console, after which the new instance then starts processing the tasks. These tasks are simple http calls to fetch data. The Queue usually has anywhere from 1 task to upto 15-20 at any time. Noticed that even with as low as 3-4 it sometimes stalls.

The logs don't show anything at all, nothing scrolls. Only when the backend instance is deleted, the log would show that the /task was terminated via console. No out of memory, no crashes, no 404.

Earlier logs and screenshots which I had captured:
[image: Requests by type]
[image: Traffic]

I am unable to add more images, but here are the ones for [Utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CYmd.png), [Memory Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PHVn.png) & [most recent memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSnXc.png) after which I had deleted the instance and the tasks resumed.

This and recent other experience has shaken my faith in Google App Engine. What  am I doing wrong? (This exact B1 backend setup with queue config has worked previously for many years!)

Comment: I was so used to calling it a "backend" but must clarify that we have already changed it to "modules/services" a year ago

Comment: I am with GCP support. Raise a support case if you have support, please.

Comment: Hi @RubénC. we still have this problem and the issue has gone unattended. Would you be able to help? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110059331